# Civil War Roads & Rails GIS

Tags: shapefile

Does anyone know where I can find a site that has US. Civil War roads and railroads (transportation routes) available in a ESRI GIS format preferably as a shapefile? I can find scanned maps, but would prefer vectors. I only need Virginia, West Virginia and Maryland, if it exist for the entire US, I will take it! A free site is wanted, but would consider commercial sites as well.

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Shapefile US Railroads, 1826-1911 available here https://my.vanderbilt.edu/jeremyatack/data-downloads/